# i have booked dates in calendarm i want to show info from datesbase on the dates

Tags: javascript, php, sql

```
    * In  javascript part  i got the dates that are booked by user on dates, i n calendar i marked that dates are unavilable, but i want to show user info on that dates 
            <script type="text/javascript">
            // Add New Dates and Block Out Booked Days Below 
            /*var unavailableDates1 = ["20-5-2016", "21-5-2016", "22-5-2016", "23-5-2016", "5-6-2016", "7-6-2016", "8-6-2016",
                                  "15-6-2016", "16-6-2016", "25-6-2016", "26-6-2016", "27-6-2016", "28-6-2016", "14-2-2016",
                                  "15-7-2016", "16-7-2016", "17-7-2016", "18-7-2016", "19-7-2016","20-7-2016","21-7-2016",
                                  ];   */
            var unavailableDates = <?php echo json_encode($arr2); ?>;
            var unavaila = <?php echo json_encode($e); ?>;
            document.write(unavailableDates);
            function unavailable(date) {

                dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1 ) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

                if($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {

                    return [true, ""];

                }else {

                            return [false, "", unavaila];

                }
            }
            $(function() {
                $("#Datepicker1").datepicker({
                    numberOfMonths:3,
                    beforeShowDay: unavailable
                }); 
            });
            </script>

        *
```

and my php code is getting  the dates from database in between start to end m, and showing calendar booked, how to show info on that

```
        <?php 


        include 'dbconfig.php';


        $query_getaway = "SELECT * FROM getaway_table; ";
        $result_getaway = $db->query($query_getaway);
         $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'category'))  .'<br>'; 
         $resort = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'resorts'))  .'<br>'; 

        if( $category != 0 ){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM booking_request where room_id = '$resort' '<br>' ";
        $result = $db->query($query);
                if( $result -> num_rows > 0 ) {




                    while( $row = $result-> fetch_assoc() )
                    {
                  $name = $row['getaway_name']." <br>";
                   $start = $row['check_in_date']." <br>";
                    $end = $row['check_out_date']." <br>";
                    $guest_n[]= $row['guest_name'];
                    $guest_number[]= $row['guest_phone'];


                    $arr1 = range(strtotime($row['check_in_date']),strtotime($row['check_out_date']), "86400");


                    array_walk_recursive($arr1, function(&$element) { $element = date("j-n-Y", $element); });

                  foreach ($arr1  as $value)

                  {
                      $arr2[]= $value;
                  }
               $arrt= (array_merge($guest_n, $guest_number));
               //print_r($arrt);
               foreach($arrt as $val)
               {
                   echo $arr_val[]=$val;
               }

        $arr[]= $value;

        }
        }
        else { echo "select" ;}

        ?>
```

how to get the result to show user details on mousehover on dates from db.